# Pixi.js: Animate circle (improving performance)

Tags: performance, pixi.js

I would like to animate 1000 circles (position, radius, alpha, fill, stroke).
The current method I am using involves updating some properties on the Graphics object but then also clearing and recreating the circle for each draw().

```
 holder = new PIXI.Graphics();
 holder.lineStyle(strokeWidth, strokeColor, strokeOpacity);
 holder.beginFill(color);
 holder.drawCircle(r, r, r);
 holder.endFill();
```

This is unfortunately too expensive ... Is there any way to avoid clearing the circle or another approach that can speed this render loop up?

Comment: If you have a manageable number of spicies of circles: e.g. Combinations of stroke attributes, then you can use a sprite sheet. This is much faster than graphics objects. You can scale the spirites if you need different sizes.

Comment: That should be species not spicies

Answer (score 0):

if you hold a reference on each holder (for example in an array) you just can update their positions / tinting etc.. on each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of things to improve performance:

1. Make sure that you only use one PIXI.Graphics (or as least as possible objects) object which is created on initialisation and not on every animFrame. Draw all of the circles on that object and only manipulate those.
2. If you don't have to change properties on every single circle try to group similar ones and you can generateTexture from them which then still allows you to manipulate position, size and alpha.
3. Try to limit updating the circles so it doesn't happen on every draw. Do you really need 60 updates per second? If you do, try to group circles and update for example 100 of them in one frame, next 100 in next frame and so on...

I'm not sure what exactly do you want to achieve with 1000 circles but if you add an example to your questions I can be more specific with optimisation tips.